# Java Swing, JButton not showing on a panel with a grid layout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, grid-layout

I've been trying to add a grid layout of buttons onto a jpanel, but nothing shows up on the jpanel when I run the code.

public class MyFrame extends JFrame{

```
public static final int WIDTH = 800;
public static final int HEIGHT = 900;

MyFrame() {
    this.setTitle("Percolation Simulation");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setVisible(true);
    
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setBounds(0, 0, WIDTH, 600);
    mainPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
    mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    
    this.add(mainPanel);
    
    
    mainPanel.add(new JButton());
    mainPanel.add(new JButton());
    mainPanel.add(new JButton());
    
    mainPanel.setVisible(true);
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
}
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyGt3.png)Output of code

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. It shows 3 large buttons for me.

Comment: @Unmitigated are you suggesting that the problem lies in the software and not the code?

Answer (score 0):

- Don't use `null` layouts, they aren't helping you
- `this.setVisible(true)` is irrelevant, Swing components by default are visible (with the exception of window based classes)
- Swing is lazy, so modifying a UI which is presented on the screen will not be immediately update.  In your case, simply make `this.setVisible` the last statement, otherwise you need to `revalidate` and `repaint` the container which has changed, in order to trigger a new layout and paint pass.
- Setting the size of the window is ill-advised. This will make the visible content area `size - window decoration insets` which may cause you issues.  Better to set the preferred size of the content (or just let the layout managers do their jobs) and `pack` the window around it

## For example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MyFrame();
            }
        });
    }

    public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

        public static final int WIDTH = 800;
        public static final int HEIGHT = 900;

        MyFrame() {
            this.setTitle("Percolation Simulation");
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel() {
                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return new Dimension(MyFrame.WIDTH, MyFrame.HEIGHT);
                }
            };
            mainPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
            mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout());

            mainPanel.add(new JButton(" "));
            mainPanel.add(new JButton(" "));
            mainPanel.add(new JButton(" "));

            this.add(mainPanel);

            this.pack();
            this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            this.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not all heroes wear capes, thank you

Comment: @randypahang Who says I don't ware capes 